# Intellij idea Javascript formatting and highlighting

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I am new to developing webapps in Intellij so this may be a simple question. How do I get it to properly display Javascript syntax when I am editing scripts within an HTML page. For example when I create an external file with a .js extension it properly formats the Javascript, but when I have in in-file Javascript function it fails to pick up on it and displays it as plain text. Is this a limitation of the community edition?

Comment: I personally use a different IDE for JS and IntelliJ for Java so I've not actually tried that but my first guess would be - does the script tag in the .html page say that the language is JavaScript? Perhaps IntelliJ doesn't format it because it doesn't know (even if JS is the default). It could also be a limitation in Community Edition. It seems to be handling Java OK, but I know there are a bunch of JS development stuff that is part of WebStorm and Ultimate that isn't in the free version.

Comment: I think you can't do this with intellij itself (may with an plugin). If you need best js support, you should use jet brains web storm.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a limitation of the comunity edition. If you go to the [comparison page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) you will notice a few differences:

[image]

Comment: Community edition should support basic JS autoformat. It's not a supper complicated feature. Even Emacs does it.

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov you might want to suggest that to [JB](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com)